# Create a Button whose background changes when another button is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've a wrap panel with some buttons. When the button is pressed background is changed to red else background is transparent. If I pressed another button, background of previous button should change to transparent and the background of recently pressed button should change to red. How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm sure there are lots of ways to do this! One way would be to use a `DataTrigger`.

To do this, you would bind the button's command property to a command whose `Execute` function set a variable in the view model:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SetButton1Command}"/>
<Button Command="{Binding SetButton2Command}"/>
```

These functions could do something simple, like toggle a bool. I'll assume you do that as there are only two buttons. More buttons would need an enum or something (or just use a `RadioButton` and this whole thing gets a lot easier).

With the `bool` property being set, I would then use a `DataTrigger` to set the background:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SetButton1Command}"/>
    <Button.Style>
      <Style>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FlagProperty}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    <Button.Style>
</Button>
```

If you instead used `RadioButton` (something I would recommend) you just trigger on "IsChecked" being changed (with a RelativeSource or ElementName binding).

Answer (score -1):

This is for winforms, but will work on webforms as well. 
Here it is:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;

        if (btn.Name == "button1")
        { 
            button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            button2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Put two buttons on a form, wire them to the same event.

hope this helps.

Comment: -1 This question is about WPF, not winForms or web forms. While this is a method that could work in WPF, it is not a standard way of doing so. The MVVM approach is preferred in WPF apps.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET my bad, misread it.